# Newline in copyright notice string (XMP pdf metadata)

Tags: pdf, xmp

I'm wondering if it is possible to include a newline character in the XMP pdf copyright notice string.
I've tried using \\ or \newline but with no sucess...
See code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Donald Duck},
    pdftitle={Uncle Scrooge},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright © 2014 by Mickey.\\ All rights reserved.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

As the picture below demonstrates, the newline character is ignored for some reason...
How to have it right?

[image]

Comment: Try with `\012`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hyperxmp` passes the XMP strings to `hyperref`, which disables `\\`. But luckily `hyperref` instead provides (via its PDF encodings) the commands `\textLF` and `\textCR`, and also allows specifying characters in octal notation, eg. as `\012`. 
So,

```
  pdfcopyright={Copyright © 2014\textLF by Mickey.\012All rights reserved.}
```

will be presented as three lines:

[image: XMP]